# How to use ol li and table side by side with no html validation error?

Tags: html, css

[image: This image will make you clear how i want to show these data.]

How to use ol li and table side by side with no html validation error?
I need to show these kind of data.
I have about thousand lines of data with pagination. How can i integrate it?

Comment: What does the HTML code look like?

Comment: Just use a `table`, not an `ol`. This is tabular data.

Comment: I also need serial numbers in first column too.

Comment: As what I understood. The english words are actually in `ol` and `li` format and the other language words are in a single table. and now you want to show those two elements side by side. right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border='0' class='table-list' style="width:100%;">
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" style="padding-right:20px;">
            <ol>
                <li>Snow Partridge</li>
                <li>Tibetan Snowcock</li>
            </ol>
        </td>
        <td valign="top" style="padding-right:20px;">
            <ul>
                <li>लरवान</li>
                <li>कोङ्मा हिउकुखुरा</li>
            </ul>
        </td>
        <td valign="top" style="padding-right:20px;">
            <ul>
                <li>Chinese Version</li>
                <li>Chinese Version</li>
            </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I have used this as the best solution.

Answer (score 3):

Use counter CSS on first cell of each row then you style.
Selector:  `tr :first-child` should be okay .
more about CSS COUNTER: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Counters

Comment: In this , only a table is hidden, olé ol :)

Comment: View this link, scroll it down and see. http://nepalbirds.com/gallery/common-birds-2/

Answer (score 2):

GCyrillus is right: I create a CSS counter "mycount" and then I use a class attribute every time I want to print.
Here The CSS code:

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
    counter-reset: mycount;           /* Set the counter to 0 */
}
.mycount:before{
    counter-increment: mycount;      /* Increment the counter */
    content: counter(mycount) ". "; /* Display the counter */
}
</style>
```

And the html table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="mycount"></span></td>
    <td>Snow Partridge</td>
    <td>लरवान</td>
    <td>Chinese Version</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="mycount"></span></td>
    <td>Tibetan Snowcock</td>
    <td>कोङ्मा हिउकुखुरा</td>
    <td>Chinese Version</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```